# Why does this UPDATE query not update my table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I am trying to code a user system. I am having an issue with the activation part. I can select and insert data to my table but now I am trying to create an update statement and got stuck.

```
<?PHP
include "db_settings.php";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE 'Kullanicilar' SET 'Aktivasyon' = ? WHERE 'KullaniciID'=?");
// execute the query
$stmt->execute(array('1','5'));

// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
?>
```

And I am getting error as:

> "0 records UPDATED successfully".

This is my table; https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2ta.png

[image]

I have tried by changing my 'Aktivasyon' type `int` to `char` but it also does not work.

---

EDIT:
I am trying to make this a function;

```
function dataUpdate($tableName, $updateRow, $updateValue, $conditonRow, $conditionValue)
{
        include "db_settings.php";
        $q = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET $updateRow= ? WHERE $conditonRow= ?");
        $q->execute(array($updateValue,$conditionValue));
}
```

I also try this :

```
          ...
        $q = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE `$tableName` SET `$updateRow`= ? WHERE `$conditonRow`= ?");
        ...
```

How can I make this statement work?

Comment: check your db that record updated or not actually?  `$stmt->execute(array(1,5));`  and filed should be `int (small int,medium int or int)`

Comment: @Ahmet problem with your query single quotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using wrong quotes. You are basically saying "update this table, set this *string* to something when the string *KullaniciID* equals the string *5*" which of course never is true.

You should use backticks ` if you want to specify column names. Then your query would work. Usually you don't even need those, but for some reason MySQL world is always adding them.

So to clarify, this is a string: `'KullaniciID'` and this is a column name: `` `KullaniciID` ``.

Also you should not send integers as strings. It causes extra conversions or even errors with more strict databases.

Comment: Thanks i got it but i try to make this as a function and i am stuck again. Can you please take a look my edit ?